# Configurar servidor para ejecutar un archivo PHP en X tiempo

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

soy un novato en el tema de programacion web, y se que la pregunta ya se ha hecho en otros momentos, pero no como yo lo pensaba.

Lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

Tengo un archivo PHP que ejecuta unas querys en una base de datos. El problema que tengo es que quiero automatizarlo para que cada inicio de mes ejecute ese archivo. Por si se lo preguntan, el archivo crea una tabla correspondiente al mes actual y actualiza algun que otro registro, nada raro.

Intente automatizarlo directamente en la base de datos pero me encontre con el problema de que en los procedimientos almacenados y los triggers las funciones estan limitadas, y creo que deberia ser mas facil hacerlo con un archivo PHP.

Les agradezco desde ya cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Yo tengo un contexto parecido al tuyo. Te cuento cómo lo hice. 1. Escribí un archivo SSH, llamado por ejemplo: `lanzar_update.sh` cuyo contenido es solamente esto: `#!/bin/bash
php /tuDirectorioHome/TuUsuario/public_html/tuCarpeta/update.php` en esa ruta por supuesto existe tu archivo (llamado `update.php` en este caso). 2. Luego programas un Cron que ejecute el archivo `lanzar_update.sh` al inicio de cada mes.

Comment: En algunos casos se pueden lanzar directamente el script desde Cron ([ver aquí algunos ejemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22358382/5587982)), yo no pude hacerlo, no recuerdo ahora el motivo, por lo tuve que recurrir a lanzar la ejecución por medio de un archivo `.sh` que sí funciona perfectamente en mi entorno (hosting compartido).

Comment: Un detalle que no comente es que estoy trabajando con Windows. Pero entiendo la idea.

Comment: En Windows sería el mismo concepto, cambiaría el tipo de archivo y la forma de llamar el script, según la ubicación de tu php, ( [aquí hay un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035091/5587982) ), o bien ( [este post a modo de tutorial](https://docs.moodle.org/36/en/Cron_with_Windows_OS) ). No sé si los ejemplos expuestos serán compatibles con tu versión de Windows, imagino que sí.